# CMake Project automake library

Tags: c++, cmake, automake

I've a CMake Project. Now I need to use [`libcpuid`](http://libcpuid.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) and [`procps`](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) which is automake.

I want to ship `so` files with executable.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a CMakeLists.txt file for `libcpuid` and `procps`

Here is an example for a CMakeLists.txt file for lipcpuid:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(libcpuid-0.1.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

# Compiler settings
if (WIN32)
    # Standard:          /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /Zm1000 /EHsc /GR
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /Zi /EHsc /GR- /MP /openmp")
endif (WIN32)

file(GLOB libcpuid_SRC  *.c *.h)

add_definitions(-DVERSION="0.1.0")

# Create a target for the library
add_library(libcpuid-0.1.0
    ${libcpuid_SRC}
)
```

Afterwards in your CMake project you can easily reference to the lib via:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libcpuid_0.1.0)

target_link_libraries(  YourProject
    libcpuid-0.1.0
)
```

Comment: How will `libcpuid_SRC` be defined ? and can't I do `target_link_libraries` just with `libcpuid` without specifying version number ?

Comment: I assume that the above listed CMakeLists.txt is placed in the libcpuid. GLOB will collect all *.c and *.h files in this directory. If you do not want to compile the lib yourself you can also follow this approach: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries